# partitioning netbook without DVD drive using gparted

Tags: gparted

HP Netbook Mini 210
    F14 xfce

I installed F14 xfce and using the entire disk.

```
Filesystem        Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/sda2         97G   4.0G  92G    5%    /
tmpfs             494M  212K  494M   1%    /dev/shm
/dev/sda1         485M  49M   211M   11%   /boot
/dev/sda4         193G  8.5G  175G   5%    /home
```

After I have installed all my programs, I need to install windows and I need visual studio.

So I was thinking of taking 20 GB from the /home directory and using that for windows.

I can use gparted. However, many posters on here think it is best to use gparted by booting from the disk. However, I cannot do this, as I don't have any DVD drivers. And I can't really afford to buy one just for this reason.

What is the best way to do this?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best would be to use [GParted Live on USB](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/liveusb.php). Follow the instructions for [creating a GParted USB under Linux](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/liveusb.php#linux-setup).