# How Do I Erase A HDD Without An OS?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot

I tried installing Windows onto my hard drive and it froze on the "Beginning Setup" screen. I've tried almost everything from changing to legacy and safe mode; I've run out of ideas.

How do I erase the HDD without an OS?

Comment: Couldn't you use the Windows install disk to delete the partitions on the device and then recreate them?

Comment: When i try to install windows it allows me to choose the language and choose which version but instead of letting me select which drive to install on it gets stuck in a never ending loading screen that says setup is starting

Comment: Please check : http://superuser.com/questions/218873/partitioning-netbook-without-dvd-drive-using-gparted

Comment: Close voter: How is this a request for a product, service, or learning recommendation?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Hiren's Boot CD. [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a Linux Live USB in another computer, and then boot it in the damaged one. Use Linux to delete the whole damaged volume and reinstall Windows normally.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your disk is bad.  You should be able to boot from pretty much any OS disk and format your drive.  This happened to me, and it was a great excuse to tell my wife I had to spend some money to upgrade to an SSD :)

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the Windows OS cd and move to repair option there you can find troubleshoot in that go to command prompt and type

> diskpart

Here you can find the HDD when typing this command list disk you will get HDD list.
[image]

Then select the disk which you want to format (for example)

> select Disk 0

[image]

After selecting type **clean** it will format the entire Hard Disk

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but unfortunately when i press the repair option it gets stuck in the infinite loading screen.

Comment: Try connecting as a secondary disk in working machine and format